# Apply function according to IF

Tags: swift, uitableview

```
var amtOfLikes = 0
@IBAction func whenPressed (sender:UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent){
        likesLbl.text = "Likes \(amtOfLikes+1)"
        likeBtn.setTitle("- Like", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

Our problem is that we want to make sure that IF the label of LIKEBTN is "+ Like", then amtOfLikes+1 and change the LIKEBTN into "- Like". Then another IF LIKEBTN is "-Like" which is inevitably true in this case, as it has been changed, then amtOfLikes-1. Its fairly simple, but we aren't sure how to write the code.

Comment: @iDeveloper do you know how to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Start by keeping the state of your data:

```
var liked: Bool = false
```

In the click handler you can just change its value:

```
@IBAction func whenPressed(sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.liked = !self.liked
}
```

and you can actually implement the code in the `didSet` callback:

```
var liked: Bool = false {
   didSet {
       let title = liked ? "- Like" : "+ Like"
       likeBtn.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   }
}
```

or you can split it into multiple functions:

```
var liked: Bool = false {
   didSet {
       updateUIState()
   }
}

private func updateUIState() {
    let title = liked ? "- Like" : "+ Like"
    likeBtn.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Changing `amtOfLikes` should be the same. Don't change UI directly. Change your model and then update your UI based on your model.

Comment: will this work with recurring items in a table view cell? thank you!

Comment: @SelenaRoseGomez This is nothing special and there is nothing special about table view cells. This is just a common separation of model and UI. With a table, you have a `dataSource`, that's your model. `updateUIState` is when you call `tableView.reloadData()`. You see? `UITableView` already uses it.

Comment: Okay i see. Thank you for your help.